# Wildcarding words of different length with regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to replace a lot of meta keyword tags from HTML.

i.e. `meta name="keywords" content="Some Content"`

I think I need to use a regular expression as the content varies for every page. However, the content can be various lengths, so I'm struggling to find the regular expression to use?

Thanks in advance.

Ben

Comment: Regex is generally a bad HTML parser, if you tell us what language you're trying to accomplish this with there might be a better solution.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) before going any further.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: So finally, you want to replace what with what?

Comment: I actually want to simply remove them all from hundreds of HTML documents. I was thinking of using regex, but am open to other suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex (with php's `preg_replace()` function, for example):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=name=").+?(?=")/i', 'replacement', $htmlCode);
```

Using **positive lookbehind** and **positive lookahead**.